# Twig loop through array with "."

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, twig

I'm trying to create a loop to display information about products I have in a MYSQL database. I'm using MeekroDB and had to do a JOIN Query to get all the data in a single array:

```
$result = DB::queryFullColumns("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT, CATEGORY WHERE product.categoryID = category.ID");
$app->render('product_list.html.twig', array('products' => $result, ));
```

I get this array from the operation:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(8) 
{ ["PRODUCT.ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["PRODUCT.categoryID"]=> string(2) 
    "17" ["PRODUCT.name"]=> string(7) "Pants 1" ["PRODUCT.description"]=> 
    string(23) "These are pants number1" ["PRODUCT.image_path"]=> string(0) 
    "" ["PRODUCT.price"]=> string(5) "10.00" ["CATEGORY.ID"]=> string(2) 
    "17" ["CATEGORY.name"]=> string(5) "Pants" } [1]=> array(8) { 
    ["PRODUCT.ID"]=> string(1) "3" ["PRODUCT.categoryID"]=> string(2) "17" 
    ["PRODUCT.name"]=> string(7) "Pants 1" ["PRODUCT.description"]=> 
    string(23) "These are pants number1" ["PRODUCT.image_path"]=> string(0) 
    "" ["PRODUCT.price"]=> string(6) "$10.00" ["CATEGORY.ID"]=> string(2) 
    "17" ["CATEGORY.name"]=> string(5) "Pants" }
}
```

I would then like to loop through it to display some information, here is my code to do so (using twig):

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr><td><a href="/admin/product/edit/{{product.PRODUCT.ID}}">{{product.PRODUCT.name}}</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="productListTd">{{ product.PRODUCT.price }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="productListTd">{{ product.PRODUCT.description }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="productListTd">{{ product.CATEGORY.name }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><hr></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work and doesn't return any value.
In other part of my project I do the same and it works, the only difference being that I don't join tables there.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you already try using `product['PRODUCT.name']`?

Comment: Well it works with product['PRODUCT.name'] , turns out it was really easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solve this by using the array notation in Twig, as documented [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html). In your case, all you must do is

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr><td><a href="/admin/product/edit/{{ product['PRODUCT.ID'] }}">{{product['PRODUCT.name']}}</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="productListTd">{{ product['PRODUCT.price'] }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="productListTd">{{ product['PRODUCT.description'] }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="productListTd">{{ product['CATEGORY.name'] }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><hr></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```